# Passing char into a string through a function

Tags: c, cs50

Week 2 Crack, unable to compile due to passing error of char and string

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>

char compare(char alpha, string hashed, string password, string salt, int x);
int main(void)
{
    string k ="e";
    string salt = "12";
    string crypted = crypt(k,salt);
    printf("%s\n",crypted);

    string pass[1];
    char poss [] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
    int p = strlen(poss);
    printf("%i\n",p);

    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        pass[0][0] = compare(poss[i], crypted, pass[0], salt, 0); //no.21
        printf("%s",pass[0]);//no.22
    }
}
char compare(char alpha, string hashed, string password, string salt, int x)
{
    password[0] = alpha;//no.27
    string q = crypt(password,salt);//no.28
    if(strcmp(q, hashed))//no.29
    {
        printf("%s",password);//no.31 
        exit(0); 
    }
    else
    {
        return alpha;//no.36
    }
}
```

My expectations on how this program should run

line 21, these args are passed into a function that return a char

line 27, char 'a' is passed into password[0][0] location. making the password[0] string an 'a'

line 29, the strcmp func will compare string q against the hashed.

line 29, since it is false, it will go to line 36, which return char 'a' into pass[0][0] at line 21.

line 22, will print out 'a'.

Error:

line 27 error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

line 28 error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type'const char *';

line 31 error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'

Comment: `password` is a string and `password[0]` is a `char`. You can't do `[]` on a `char`. In `password[0][x]`, what are the `0` and `x` supposed to represent?

Comment: There's seems to be some mixup between `pass` in the `main` function and `password` in the `compare` function.

Comment: Also note that in the `main` function, `pass[0]` is an ***uninitalized*** pointer, you can't dereference it in any way.

Comment: Why do you write `char poss [] = {'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};` instead of `char poss[] = "abcde";`?

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do? It's not at all obvious.

Comment: The first argument of `crypt()` is supposed to be a string. In `crypt(password[0],salt);` you're passing `password[0]`, which is just a single character, not a string.

Comment: Line 31: If you want to print a single character, use `%c`. `%s` is for strings. It seems like you really need to review the difference between strings and characters.

Comment: This is my main complaint about CS50 in C, it uses that useless `string` type alias which hides the fact that strings in C are array of characters and that such arrays decays to pointers. Please try to find some other tutorials and books that doesn't attempt to hide the complexities of the language and instead teaches them.

Comment: @Blaze "You can't do [] on a char". Can you elaborate further? I'm confused as i thought you can have a char array.
password[0][x], with x will be 0, i wanted it to be an identical to pass[0][0]. This code is part of a larger code. I only showed one for-loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how can i fix the pass[0] ? I leave it empty because the compare function supposed to pass char into pass[0]. Is pass[0] a variable or a pointer?

Comment: @Barmar I did not know you can do that to char, i thought you have to follow the same rules as in a string array, for ex: string a[] = {"joly","mickey","kid"}; can i do this string as string a[] = {"joly mickey kid"};?

Comment: *"I'm confused as i thought you can have a char array. "* Yes, and `password` will point to such a char array. As such, `password[0]` is just one char and you can't dereference it further.

Comment: @Barmar essentially i want the compare function to use the char poss(char alpha) to generate a string pass (string password) inside the function. 
This new password with the string salt(string salt), will be encrypted into string q.
Then compare the string hashed against string q. if it matches, display the password then exit the program. If not, return the password into pass[0][0]. 
In this scenario, the password is a single character, so that is why i use pass[0][0] because i believe it means the first character of the first string.

Comment: You need to get a good textbook. A string is an array of char. A char is just a single number containing the character code, it can't be divided any more.

Comment: So if you have `string password = "blah"`, `password[0]` is the character `'b'`. `password[0][x]` makes no sense, because you can't have anything smaller than `'b'`.

Comment: @Blaze so how can i manipulate the string so i can adjust the the individual chars inside them? In this case, i want string password first letter to be one of the letters in the char poss for every loop iteration.

Comment: You can have an array of strings, like `string several_passwords[] = {"password1", "password2", "password3" };` Then `several_passwords[0]` is `"password1"`, and `several_passwords[0][3]` is `'s'`.

Comment: @Barmar so this is the original work. 
https://github.com/shahril-salim/crack/blob/master/1
I would appreciate if you could comment on it. Been frustrated at it. It seems that I'm weak at array, string and char.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  can you recommend resources where to learn?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials, and books are invaluable as are actual classes. Unfortunately I don't know about any good online resource for beginners.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that unfortunate but thank you for your time